# Magic: the Gathering - Impending Annihilation

Tags: calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

### Background

Normal MtG rules apply here. Your solution must work regardless of any possible choices made by your opponents; assume they do whatever makes it most difficult for you to win. If you would draw a card, you may assume that you draw any card remaining in your library, regardless of shuffling.

### Puzzle Setup

You are playing in a multiplayer game of Magic.  Decks are 60+ cards, no ban list besides unglued/unhinged, maximum  four of each card unless the card says otherwise (or is a basic land).

All the other players have been eliminated, leaving only you and one opponent.  **It is your opponent's first main phase**, nothing has summoning sickness, and no spells have been cast yet on his turn.

Win the game!

(If there are multiple solutions, the best is the one which wins on the earliest turn, secondary tiebreaker is dealing the most damage)

**Your hand:**
[Angel's Grace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370545)
[Borderland Ranger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=239964)
[Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397612)
[Dark Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397401)
[Diabolic Edict](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397522)
[Glacial Ray](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370552)
[Grozoth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=83832)

**Your board:**
[Nullmage Advocate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=271178) (Tapped)
[Heritage Druid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152556) (Tapped)
[Wellwisher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393996) (Tapped)
[Door to Nothingness](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=288992)
[Near-Death Experience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=193467)
2 Mountains
2 Islands
2 Plains
2 Forests
1 Swamp

**Your graveyard:**
[Ancestral Tribute](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=30555)
[Cabal Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382877)
[Controvert](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=122121)
[Elephant Ambush](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=32919)
[Hell's Thunder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386326)
[Garza's Assassin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=122051)

**Your library:**
*Whatever you want*

**Your life:**
8

**Opponent's hand:**
[Decree of Annihilation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386288)
[Dispel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401858)
[Mental Misstep](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230066)
[Rift Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370469)
[Rift Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370469)

**Opponent's board:**
[Sulfuric Vortex](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382379)
[Telepathy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189910)
12 Mountains
1 Island

**Opponent's graveyard:**
Nothing

**Opponent's library:**
39 Mountains

**Opponent's life:**
10

Comment: This question is frustratingly open-ended. By asking us to devise a strategy that beats any possible opposing play, you're asking us to beat _every_ possible opposing play, and since it's the opponent's turn, there are dozens if not hundreds of possible lines, I don't want to work out each of one hundred lines of play.

Comment: There are actually fairly few lines, given that his entire deck is lands, and a few blatantly fail (for example, any line in which he doesn't attempt to cast Decree is clearly going to lead to an immediate win on your part).

Comment: There, removed a few cards to make it a little simpler.

Comment: There were a lot of opponent lines that ultimately lose, but delay your win for a turn or two, which means for scoring purposes you'd have to play them out (how would you score that anyway, average of lines, worst of?)

Comment: I retract my comment about the opponent having too many lines of play. I had been thinking that the opponent had the option to cycle Decree, which opened up a lot more avenues, but if they do that, you can win on your first turn, so they have to cast it. Things are much less complicated then. My apologies.

Comment: If you end up having to play it out for multiple turns, your score is the result of the line that is worst for you - or, to put it another way, the line for which you opponent has no better plays for which you do not have counter plays.  That said, if you have to worry about that kind of scoring, you're probably not finding an ideal solution.

Comment: I should just stop posting until I take a few more hours to think on this. I thought your modifications had made the puzzle unwinnable, then I thought I had it solved, then I realized I'd made a mistake and it was back to being unwinnable. But a quick check of puzzle intent: Are you aware that AP-NAP means that Near-Death + Sulfuric Vortex kills you, even if you start the turn at 1 life?

Comment: That's not an issue, but something else might have been - replaced Fireball with Glacial Ray; should make it work better.  Also, made opponent's deck more mountain-heavy, so there's no question what a Cycle'd decree will get him.

Comment: Well I'm stumped. Your opponent suspends both bolts, casts Decree, saving Dispel for Counterspell and Misstep for Ritual if you cast them. You then have 8 life plus a useless NDE and no other cards. Before your second draw step you will be hit with two vortex triggers and two bolts, for ten damage total. I can't see a way out. In the original version this was beatable because you had the untapped Nullmage to kill Vortex (and Edict killed the Platinum Angel).

Comment: The title of the puzzle may or may not be a hint - but it's *definitely* winnable now.

Comment: And you understand that "Glacial Ray myself, edict myself and pay 3 to assassin, take 2 in the upkeep and win with NDE" doesn't work because of intervening if clauses? If so, I cannot fathom how you intend to beat the above line from the opponent, and I eagerly await someone else figuring it out.

Comment: Yep, that's not a problem.

Comment: Is there something special about being in a multiplayer game if only one opponent is left? Couldn't it have just been a regular game? :p

Comment: Well, it's hard to explain how a regular game of vintage got to 12 lands :p

Comment: I was convinced that was just another red herring, I actually checked the comp rules to see if there was some esoteric difference between a multiplayer game down to 2, and a regular game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that was tough, but here it is, infinite damage on turn 1.

The opponent suspends two Rift Bolts, casts Decree, holding up Dispel for Counterspell and Misstep for Ritual.

Untap, take 2 from Sulfuric vortex, and draw [Street Wraith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370428).
Cycle [Street Wraith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370428) to draw [Bazaar of Baghdad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253589).
Play [Bazaar of Baghdad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253589) and activate it to draw and discard [Call to the Netherwold](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=108832) and [Fatestitcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=176456).
Cast [Call to the Netherwold](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=108832) for its Madness cost of zero, returning [Street Wraith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370428).
Cycle [Street Wraith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370428) to draw [Lion's Eye Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383000).
Crack [Lion's Eye Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383000) for UUU, and Unearth [Fatestitcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=176456).
Use [Fatestitcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=176456) to untap [Bazaar of Baghdad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253589), tap it to draw and discard Fatestticher and [Basking Rootwalla](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393880) (casting [Basking Rootwalla](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393880) for Madness zero).
Unearth the second [Fatestitcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=176456), untap [Bazaar of Baghdad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253589), draw and discard [Mulldrifter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405312) and [Dread Return](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389491).
Flashback [Dread Return](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389491) on [Mulldrifter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405312), sacrificing all three creatures, drawing two cards.
Play [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382866), [Ancestral Recall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382841).
Play [Lion's Eye Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383000), [Lion's Eye Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383000), [Ideas Unbound](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=88789), crack [Lion's Eye Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383000) for UUURRR with Ideas on the stack.
Play [Pestermite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370440), [Seething Song](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243487), [Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397698).
Make infinite [Pestermites](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370440) and deal infinite damage.

Today I learned you can win a game of Magic with five life and a one card hand. Cool.

To prove that "Opponent cycles Decree" is beatable: The opponent cycles Decree and casts both Rift Bolts at you. You untap, Vortex on the stack you use Nullmage to kill the Vortex and Wellwisher to gain 1 life, thus surviving to your draw phase. From there you play Bazaar, draw Lotus + Ancestral, and skip straight to that part of the above combo.

If the opponent casts a rift bolt at one of your creatures, you'll survive into your main phase and win as above.

Comment: And apparently you can do it in more than one way, since (past your third card) our solutions share nothing in common!  Well done.  Might want to include the proof that you can beat a Cycle'd decree, but that's not too hard.

Comment: Now I'm curious as to what you were doing, the only lines I could find were Flashback or Unearth. Flashback doesn't do anything (not enough life for Deep Analysis, the only good one), and the only Unearthable that does anything is Stitcher.

Comment: Hint: What vintage deck are you playing here?  (Also, your second proof doesn't work, since you don't have the life to pay for cycling any more)

Comment: Made it Vintage legal, just for you. Proof skips straight to the end stage of the combo, probably should have specified that. I was thinking your solution dealt infinite damage, which I don't think is possible without Dread Return -> Draw cards -> Do broken stuff. I guess you can dredge Narco Narco Narco Bridge Return Flamekin and deal lethal.

Comment: Better - Narco, Narco, Narco, Bridge, Return, Balustrade Spy.  If you can't go infinite off that with all the cards in magic and a stacked deck, you're not trying.

Comment: Edit: Oh right, mill yourself for a Narco, three more bridges, two Returns, Return Kiki and Pestermite.

Comment: You mill into Narco, Bridge x3, Dread x3, and return any three creatures in magic history.  If you want ideas, I suggest Angel of Glory's Rise as one of them.

Comment: Pestermite doesn't have haste?

Comment: Details, details. Fixed, Kiki-Jiki does.

Comment: Also, Wellwisher gains you 3 life rather than 1.  Not that it matters too much.

Comment: Well if we're getting technical, 2 life. Nullmage isn't an elf.

Comment: You have near death experience in play. bringing yourself to one life will win you the game outright. just choose to deal with vortex before its triggered check resolves. This works because of APNAP order. your near death experience goes on the stack, then sulfuric vortex goes on the stack above it. you destroy vortex, then gain life, then take 2 from vortex, going to 1, then you win.

Comment: That doesn't work because of what I mentioned in the comments on the question, intervening if clauses. NDE will only trigger if you begin the upkeep at 1 life, and the trigger only wins the game if you're still at 1 when it resolves. You can't get your life total right (and Garza's assassin won't do it because you can't trigger recover without killing a creature you need to survive).